# When randomly distributing n points amongst m people, what are the odds that one certain person will get a certain amount of points?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm mostly curious about how to find this in general, but the actual problem is with 20 points and 5 people.

I know probability problems are very counterintuitive, and thus I was unsure after thinking I had found the answer, and checking it.
My first, and most solid assumption was that that one certain person would get on average exactly 4 points.
I also thought that one certain person would be more likely to get 4 points than any other certain number.
Finally I figured that the odds for getting any certain number of points were the same as how many different distributions of points would be possible with that certain person receiving that certain number of points in comparison with the total possible variations of distributions between all people.

That however left me with the odds of getting 0 points being 1771 to 10626, while getting 4 points was only 969 to 10626, for example. This was contradicting my first and second assumptions. (Although using the same methods, it was not contradictory with my first assumption for 3 people or less.)
I made a program to generate a million of these (pseudo-)random distributions and see how the results were. Now, I was skeptical because it wasn't truly random, and the numbers were generated in very quick succession, but the results were on the other end of the unexpected spectrum. Out of the one million, there were no cases of getting over 14 points, and slightly many of getting more towards the expected amount.

So, in short, I have no idea how to solve this anymore, and I couldn't be sure of the validity of any further attempts I make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to make some assumption about the process of distributing points. I will assume that points are distributed one at a time, that any person is just as likely to get the point at stage $k$, and that the decisions for the various points are independent.

Under these assumptions, if random variable $X$ is the number of points Alicia gets, then $X$ has *binomial distribution* with parameters $n$ and $p=1/m$.  For $X$ is the number of "successes" in $n$ independent trials, where the probability of success on any trial is $1/m$. The probability Alicia gets exactly $w$ points is $\binom{n}{w}(1/m)^w (1-1/m)^{n-w}$.

Comment: Hmm, yes, this does seem to be the correct solution to the problem I posted, although it does not quite match the results I've been getting in real life. Perhaps I used the wrong analogy. So out of curiosity, what would be the other ways to distribute the points, that could be considered random?

Comment: One can imagine other models of how the points were awarded. I used the most standard model for awarding the points independently and at random. It would be interesting to know what model you implicitly used in your simulation.